# Why is the name on the header smaller than the rest of the betas?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Our name, Mythology beta, is smaller than, say, Puzzling beta or Language Learning beta.

Why?

Comment: The stylesheet has the rule tacked onto the end:  `#hlogo a{font-size:20px}`, doesn't appear on the stylesheets of other betas that I've looked at.  No idea why, of course.  I will say, could be just because I'm looking too closely and seeing things that aren't there, but the title kinda looks weirdly big in 24px font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it shouldn't be the case. It's now fixed, it'll be live after our next production build.